07 jeep liberty won't start after replacing battery, alternator, and starter
0
I have a 2007 Jeep liberty sport 3.7L My battery light came on, first thing I did was replace with new battery, then my check engine light came on along with battery light. I ended up getting things check from advance auto and replaced alternator, and my starter. I then chaged my battery to make sure it was at 100 percent. My battery light went out and so did check engine light. I did all that 2 days ago, but now my battery light came back on and now jeep won't crank. I don't know what to do now. Any suggestions?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair! Did you check your battery voltage now (after it wouldn't start)?

Replacing starter, battery, and alternator with continuing failure to start may be main wiring issues; battery positive and negative cables. Are battery cable connections corroded from powdery blue/white deposits, indicating dried battery acid? Vented batteries allows acid vapors deposit and eventually eat copper wires under heavy insulation. Check one or two negative cable connections; battery to chassis and chassis to engine block.

My voltage was 14.2 and I have a 12v battery. I also did make sure there was no corrosion or Miss coloration I also have brand new terminals on. Father in law thinks maybe fusible link. Other than that maybe the computer? Thanks everyone for the input
